How to Restrict JWT and Windows Authentication Schemes to Specific Routes in ASP.NET Core?
I am building an ASP.NET Core rest API (core 8.0 with angular frontend) application that uses JWT Bearer Authentication for some routes and Windows Authentication (Negotiate) for others. However, I am facing issues where both authentication schemes seem to be applied globally, causing undesired WWW-Authenticate headers to appear in responses. Specifically:
For JWT-protected routes, I see WWW-Authenticate: Bearer, Negotiate, NTLM, but I only want WWW-Authenticate: Bearer.
For Windows-protected routes, I want only WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate.
What I Have Tried
Here is my Program.cs configuration:
// Authentication configuration
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };

     })
    .AddNegotiate(); // Windows Authentication

// Authorization policies
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("JwtAuthPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });

    options.AddPolicy("WinAuthPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
});

// Middleware configuration
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

I use [Authorize(Policy = "JwtAuthPolicy")] for JWT routes and [Authorize(Policy = "WinAuthPolicy")] for Windows Authentication routes. However, the WWW-Authenticate headers are not restricted to their respective routes.
What I Need
How can I ensure that the WWW-Authenticate header only advertises the relevant scheme (Bearer or Negotiate) depending on the route?
Is there a way to enforce this behavior through middleware or a better configuration approach?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Even though I was not able to reproduce(I have a single scheme returned in WWW-Authenticate based on the applied policy), you could register a custom IAuthenticationService implementation and override ChallengeAsync -
class MyAuthenticationService : AuthenticationService
{
...
    public override async Task ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, string? scheme, AuthenticationProperties? properties)
    {
        await base.ChallengeAsync(context, scheme, properties);
        context.Response.Headers.WWWAuthenticate = "your_custom_value";
    }
}

builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, MyAuthenticationService>();

